# How to do backend-dependent actions in org-mode export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How do I specify different actions for different export backends in org-mode?

To be more specific, I would like to export an pdf figure in latex export, while using a png in html export (in fact, a png thumbnail linking to the pdf, if that is of relevance):

```
#+CAPTION: cation of figure
#+NAME:    myfig
# case export to latex: [[file:./figure.pdf]]
# case export to html:  [[file:./figure.pdf][file:./figure.png]]
```

I tried macros and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611837/how-can-i-use-different-image-formats-for-different-exports-in-org-mode), which did not work. There are also answers on similar cases for tikz pdf/svg/png export like [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-07/msg00405.html), which do not seem to be transferable to my case.

**Note:** I initially posted this question on stackoverflow. It occured to me later that emacs stackexchange is a more appropriate site for this question. So I deleted it on stackoverflow (there were no answers) to repost it here.

Comment: In some cases you can use things like `#+begin_html` or `by-backend` macro (I think I picked it from Org wiki somewhere), example here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wvxvw/introduction-to-data-structures/master/assignment-13/assignment.org . But I'm unaware of general purpose mechanism for this.

Comment: @wvxvw: The `#+begin_html`/`#+begin_latex` blocks would be fine for a single figure or so, but I have plenty in my document. However, searching for `by-backend` macros on google lead me to the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this, using a macro provided by [fniessen](https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros/blob/master/org-macros.setup):

```
#+MACRO: if-latex-else (eval (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'latex) "$1" "$2"))
```

If more/other export-backends than LaTeX and HTML are used, a condition statement can be used instead:

```
#+MACRO: if-latex-html-else (eval (cond ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'latex) "$1") ((org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'html) "$2") (t "$3") ))
```

Usage would be something like

```
{{{if-latex-html-else([[file:./figure.pdf]], [[file:./figure.pdf][file:./figure.png]], /Figure *figure.pdf* is supposed to be here/)}}}
```

Not as short as a simple switch, but substantially better than providing native LaTeX/HTML/whatever code for every figure that is to be included.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work anymore since `org-mode` 9.2. The code should now be written as `#+MACRO: if-latex-else (eval (if (org-export-derived-backend-p org-export-current-backend 'latex) $1 $2))`. This means that you have to rewrite your org-mode files for them to be exportable.

Answer (score 1):

Using macros as the accepted answer is a great option, which I also used following this question. But there is one alternative that I started using and that some may prefer: define a `src` block with emacs-lisp and a call it with `#+CALL` for each figure we want to include.

It works like this, add the block below to your org-mode document (it can be inside a heading with the `:noexport:` tag) and change it according with your preferences.

```
#+NAME: get-filename-by-backend
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var filename="default" :exports none :results raw
  (concat "[[file:"
          (case org-export-current-backend
            (html (concat filename ".svg"))
            (twbs (concat filename ".svg"))
            (latex (concat filename ".pdf"))
            (t (concat filename ".png")))
          "]]")
#+end_src
```

Now, whenever you want to include a figure just add something like

```
#+NAME: a_name_for_this_figure_call
#+CALL: get-filename-by-backend(filename="figs/my_nice_figure")
```

and execute the block with `C-c C-c`. This will add the result as

```
#+RESULTS: a_name_for_this_figure_call
[[file:figs/my_nice_figure.png]]
```

Now you can add `#+NAME: figure_label`, `#+CAPTION: The figure caption.`, `#+ATTR_LATEX: ...`, etc above the `#+RESULTS:` line.

The *trick* here is that we get a `png` image when we are not exporting, which can be **nicely displayed** with `org-toggle-inline-images`. However, during the export **the `#+CALL:` line is re-evaluated** and we get a `pdf` image for latex export and an `svg` image for HTML export.

The advantage of this solution, compared with a macro solution, goes beyond just displaying the image inline. Since you can pass a variable to a `src` block that receives the result of another `src` block it means that you can have a `src` block using your preferred language that generates "backend dependent" export code.