# Make org-mode ToC dependent on export format

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I would like to only have a ToC in TeX/PDF export, but not when exporting to Markdown.

Is there a way to configure it like this, if need be through a LaTeX-specific command?

Comment: looks like your question is covered by the answer(s) given to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/can-i-set-up-the-org-mode-options-differently-for-different-export-targets

Comment: @Simka: thanks for pointing that out! I had forgotten about it :-( I would recommend that the OP try the "better answer" in the link above: [Can Org options be applied to specific export modes only](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64029/can-org-options-be-applied-to-specific-export-modes-only). If that works, then this question can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can org options be applied to specific export modes only?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64029/can-org-options-be-applied-to-specific-export-modes-only)